# How to return data from HTTP sucess function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to return data from `$http.then` function:

```
if(navigator.onLine){
    $http({
      method:'GET',
      url:url,
    }).success(function(data, status){
         localStorage.setItem('abc', JSON.stringify(data));
    }).then(function(){
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('abc'));   
    });
  }else{
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('abc')); 
  }
```

I am able to get the Json data from the `else` block but getting `null` value from the `then` function.

And this function is inside a service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *cannot* [`return` the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call). You need to return the promise for it, i.e. the result of the `.then` method.

Likewise, you want to return an (already fulfilled) promise for the data from the DOM storage as well.

```
if (navigator.onLine){
    return $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:url
    }).then(function(response) {
        localStorage.setItem('abc', JSON.stringify(response.data));
        return response.data;
    });
} else {
    return $q.when( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('abc')) );
}
```

Comment: when i consoled the return, i am getting `Object {data: Object, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object}`

Comment: @Anenth: Ah, sounds reasonable. Unlike the `success` callback multiple parameters, the `$http` promise yields an object, of which we are only interested in the `.data` property. Adjusted my answer.

Comment: why do we have to return the $http object ? and it does work without the return statement in the then block

Comment: It doesn't return the `$http` function, but the *Promise* it returns for the results (and actually not even that directly, since we transform the result with `then` and return another promise). The point of promises is that their callbacks will happen in the future (ajax is asynchronous! You can't `return` from callbacks), but you can chain transformations and pass promises around when the code is executing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some processing before 'returning' you could create another promise using `$q`, it would go something like this:

```
var defer = $q.defer();
if(navigator.onLine){
  $http({
    method:'GET',
    url:url,
  }).success(function(data, status){
     localStorage.setItem('abc', JSON.stringify(data));
  }).then(function(){
    defer.resolve(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('abc')));   
  });
}else{
  defer.resolve(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('abc'))); 
}
return defer.promise;
```

what this does is that even if you have a `$http` call or not, you will be returning a consistent type, no longer worrying whether you need to wait or not.

In your caller you will do something like this (**say the above code belongs to a method `foo`**):

```
foo().then(function (data) {
  // here data contains your returned JSON parsed object
}
```

Comment: No! Don't do this. No need for another `$q.defer()` when you can use `.then()`. This solution is actually quite wrong because it does not handle errors.

Comment: thanks, it works but i didnt understand is when i consoled returned value i am getting `Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}` but the data is correctly displayed within ng-repeat

Comment: @Bergi, I agree it isn't complete, but you could definitely handle that using defere.reject(err) etc. However, I think I'll agree that your solution is simpler. This makes more sense to me in my head though that's all. :)

Comment: @Anenth, the return value *is* and object that contains methods, most importantly, like `then` which you just have to call on the returned object and pass it a `function`. That function will be called when the "promise" is fulfilled.